# Best way to retrieve Google Bookmarks with IOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ios4, synchronization, bookmarks

I'm looking for a way to get and update (= synchronize) Google Bookmarks from an IOS application. Is that doable easily? I used the JS API available in Chrome in the past (in which I had nothing to do almost, at least not the synchronization), so if there is a library for IOS that has the same features I would be even more interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google bookmarks can be accessed as an rss feed, that might suit you better than the base html output... try:

```
https://www.google.com/bookmarks/find?q=&output=rss&num=10000
```

Comment: I didn't know that and it's interesting. Authentification will be definitely an issue here though...